# What is the meaning of the declaration "char (* ( *f())[])();"?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

I was grabbing information about pointers to functions when I found this declaration:

```
char (* ( *f())[])();
```

I tried to find out what is the meaning of it but I couldn't...

what does it refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It breaks down as follows:

```
         f           -- f
         f()         -- is a function returning
        *f()         -- a pointer to
       (*f())[]      -- an array of
      *(*f())[]      -- pointer to
     (*(*f())[])()   -- function returning  
char (*(*f())[])();  -- char
```

Postfix operators like `[]` and function call `()` bind before unary operators like `*`, so

```
*a[]      -- is an array of pointer
(*a)[]    -- is a pointer to an array
*f()      -- is a function returning a pointer
(*f)()    -- is a pointer to a function
```

Find the leftmost identifier and work your way out, applying those rules recursively for any function parameters.

**Edit**

In the comment to another answer, KerrekSB suggests using typedefs, which would certainly make the code scan more easily:

```
typedef char CharFunc();
typedef CharFunc *CharFuncPtr;
typedef CharFuncPtr CharFuncPtrArr[N];
typedef CharFuncPtrArr *CharFuncPtrArrPtr;
typedef CharFuncPtrArrPtr CharFuncPtrArrPtrFunc();

CharFuncPtrArrPtrFunc *f;
```

You could probably come up with a better naming convention.  But even so,

```
CharFuncPtrArrPtrFunc *f;
```

sure *looks* nicer than

```
char (*(*f())[])();
```

But is it *better*?

In my experience, the answer is often "no", *especially* when pointer types are involved.  What is the function that `f` points to supposed to look like?  How do I call it?  What parameters am I supposed to pass to it?  What do I do with the value returned by the function `f` points to?  How do I use it in an expression?  I have to look up the definition of `CharFuncPtrArrPtrFunc`, which means I also have to look up the definition of `CharFuncPtrArrPtr`, and `CharFuncPtrArr`, etc., etc., etc., then I have to mentally puzzle out the resulting syntax for the call.

`char (*(*f())[])();` borders on total unreadability, but it tells me at a glance *how* I should call the function `f` points to and how to use the return value.

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter would indicate what they think I got wrong so I could fix it.

Answer (score 2):

[declare f as function returning pointer to array of pointer to function returning char](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%28*+%28+*f%28%29%29%5B%5D%29%28%29%3B)

Comment: Is there any place to learn this kind of complex declarations?

Comment: @Tahil: See this:  [C Right-Left Rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html)

Comment: @Robert Allan Hennigan Leahy Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Tahlil: The question is: Why would you want to learn this, other than to win pub quizzes and impress girls? It's not really necessary for *any* decent real-world programming.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's rare to find types this obnoxious in the wild, but they do crop up occasionally (I've written some code that used a lookcup table to call parsing functions based on file name and type, and the lookup function declaration was *almost* that ugly).

Comment: @JohnBode: It might be more useful to spend your time on learning about `typedef` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: In my experience, typedefs cause more problems than they solve, especially where pointers are concerned.  Ugly as the declaration is, it tells you *exactly* how it's supposed to be used in an expression, as opposed to digging through several layers of typedefs and trying to puzzle out what the call should look like.

Comment: @Tahlil Since it's three-star programming (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer), you should never use something like this in practice. However, learning the parts that make up this complex type is quite useful. Like being able to tell the difference between `char *foo[3];` and `char (*foo)[3]`. And, I believe SO is one of the best places to learn these details. It taught me quite a lot in this respect...

Comment: @JohnBode: You don't need to hide pointers in typedefs in order to make declarations simpler. It's perfectly OK to alias function and array types.